# Decrypting ConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, connection-string

I've been reading about encryption and decryption of certain parts of the web.config for C#/ASP applications and I am successful in encrypting the connectionstring of the web.config for my application.  My problem is decrypting.  I'm using the standard code to encrypt and decrypt but it modifies the web.config.  Locally it works fine since when it does modify the web.config I can save it and it will still run but when I upload it to a remote server then it doesn't work.

The error I'm getting is

> Configuration Error  Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Failed to decrypt using provider
>   'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider:
>   Bad Data

Encrypting

```
try
{
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
    if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
       section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider");
       config.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 

    }
```

Decrypting

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
{
    section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
    config.Save();
}
```

I call the decrypting method whenever the page loads but it doesn't work and it gives me the error above.

I do not have access to the host server at all.  So using the command line is not an option.

Comment: Just curious, why do you manually need to decrypt the connection strings in your app?  Just accessing `WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` will handle decrypting the config file for you if it is encrypted.

Comment: It was just the design that was handed to me.  I'm revising the code now to do just that.  I'm assigning the Connectionstring from the C# code behind to the ASP SQLDataSource.

Comment: I tried assigning this in the code behind but am still getting an error.  I placed the code during page_load for one of the asp pages for testing purposes.

Comment: String cString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnectionString"].ConnectionString; NameOfSqlDataSource.ConnectionString = cString;

Comment: Have you tried just assigning the connection string declaritively in the .aspx page?  Something like `<asp:SqlDataSource ConnectionString="NameOfConnectionString" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the same decryption key is available on the remote server that you have locally. This would be the [machine key element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx).

Comment: I would like to but I don't have access to that remote server.  Any other way around it or way I can encrypt the connection string that doesn't involve importing files to the server?

Comment: You just need to add the machineKey settings in the remote web.config. You have access to that - right? If not - you can't fix it.

Comment: I have access to that and I'm adding the machinekey code right now and I will test it.  4GuysGonnaRolla didn't mention that when I was reading their article. =/

Comment: I added a machinekey code but I'm still getting the same error. Here is my sample machinekey code that I placed inside the <system.web> tag.

Comment: <machineKey validationKey="E2ECE715B5718BB3B9261FEA573DEEECA1F78EBE3E5B57E261AC008DD8CB17A0F859BAA6C99AA51A8A397078450A9332B9F5230049624A2C440CAA44EB74D708" decryptionKey="CFB66DE0C68A76DED07A092AB7ABC3831574AF3AA51C02FD" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

Comment: You may not have access, but you need determine to the System.Web.dll version in the Microsoft.NET framework directory. Version 4.0.30319.206 fixed an issue with decrypting keys. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/28/asp-net-security-update-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can [create and export an RSA Key Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede.aspx) but you'll still need access to the remote server to import the container.

I don't believe that the machineKey element is relevant here BTW. From MSDN:

> Key containers with local machine scope (useMachineContainer"true") are stored in a hidden folder at %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the scenario is you're trying to encrypt the web.config locally before pushing it to your hosting provider/remote server.  Steve Rowbotham's answer on this question is correct in that you'll need the same RSA Key container on both your development machine and the remote server to be able to encrypt locally and decrypt remotely.

Can you take a different route and encrypt the web.config as part of your deployment process?  We use MsDeploy to handle encrypting the config file during deployment and I can provide some sample code if you would like it.

Alternatively, when you application first loads (during the Application_Start event in global.asax) you could check if the connectionStrings section of the web.config is encrypted and then encrypt it.  You shouldn't have to decrypt the web.config manually...

Comment: I am not sure how to use MsDeploy.  Though if it has anything to do with the remote server, it would be next to impossible to modify anything on it.  The red tape alone to request for such changes will take more than the alloted time for the application.

Comment: So basically changing anything on the remote server is out of the picture then?  I would try encrypting the connectionStrings in the Application_Start event as I mentioned above.  That way your app takes care of doing the encryption and you don't need anything else outside of that.